# How to save diff output between two directories?

Tags: git, kernel, diff, source-code, patch

I'm running

```
diff -rq linux-4.15-rc9/ ubuntu-bionic/ > ubuntu.diff
```

but the output is just a bunch of lines with:

```
Files linux-4.15-rc9/tools/perf/util/metricgroup.c and ubuntu-bionic/tools/perf/util/metricgroup.c differ
```

I wanted a large file with all the actual diffs (line insertions and deletions) between each file

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the `-q` option since that is what is generating your list of files that are different.

Something like

```
diff -Naur /path/to/original /path/to/changed
```

Should generate what you want.  If it does, simply redirect output to a file to use used as a patch.

```
diff -Naur /path/to/original /path/to/changed > /path/to/my_changes.patch
```

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/patch-command-examples